# Is it bad technique to use a after_create callback in the model to set a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, account

I'm using devise in a rails 4 app. 
What I'd like to do is, upon account creation, assign a random 6 digit account number to the account (in the column `:number`).

Rather than going through the process of overriding the registrations controller, I would like to simply add in a method of the following form (in the model .rb)

```
after_create :set_number

def set_number
  self.number = GET_RANDOM_NUMBER
  self.save
end
```

Is this bad practice? Should I instead override the controller and do this in the create method?

Answer (score 2):

NO it is not bad practice.

You can also do it like

```
after_initialize :set_number, :if => :new_record?

def set_number
  self.number = GET_RANDOM_NUMBER
  self.save
end
```